# cannot extend Process interface with index.d.ts in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a barebones project on this [github](https://github.com/mikesol/tsc-interface-ext) with the following basic structure:

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

`index.d.ts`

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Process {
        browser: boolean;
    }
}
```

`index.ts`

```
const x = process.browser;
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "tsc-interface-ext",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.5",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

But in spite of the `index.d.ts` file, Typescript still returns an error saying `[ts] Property 'browser' does not exist on type 'Process'.` I thought that the `index.d.ts` would add the necessary extension on a project-wide basis, but apparently not.

The hack is related to the fact that `nextjs` appends a browser property to the process and does a couple other wacky things that require polyfills to the server's global namespace, which runs into the same isuse.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this sort of interface-extending within a project? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript ignores `index.d.ts` when `index.ts` exists because it assumes that `index.d.ts` might be generated from `index.ts` and `index.ts` is more up-to-date.  Renaming `index.d.ts` to another name (for example, `declarations.d.ts`) will fix the problem.